# How can I use a custom path for Azure function app functions

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, localhost, func

I have initialized a new function app in Azure using Azure functions core tools with language set to typescript. I have one test function called MyTestFunction which returns some http response when called.

The function resides in a folder named after the function itself, in c:/dev/aztest/MyTestFunction/index.ts

Typescript files are compiled to aztest/dist folder as defaulted.

How would I configure host.json file in the root or function.json file residing within each function folder in a way that the root for all function app functions would be c:/dev/aztest/src/api/{functionFolderHere}

If I just change the paths, azure "func start" command claims no job functions are found. If I move them back to "aztest" root it works.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to move your functions from root to a nested folder structure? v3 Az Funcs don’t allow you to have a flexible folder structure. You can add your index.ts files nested like that, but your function.json file will need to stay in the current folder structure in root of your project. You will then point to the new location of the ts file in the function.json file. 

v4 will allow flexible folder structures [read more](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-functions-version-4-of-the-node-js-programming-model-is-in/ba-p/3773541).

Answer (score 0):

> How would I configure host.json file in the root or function.json file residing within each function folder in a way that the root for all function app functions would be c:/dev/aztest/src/api/{functionFolderHere}

As *Colby* mentioned, if you are using V3 or previous versions, you can't modify the default folder structure, you can find the same in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=windows-setting-the-node-version&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#supported-versions).

But if you are using V4 version, it supports flexible folder structure according to your requirement:
[image]

you can use the [`scriptFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#folder-structure)  parameter in `function.json` to locate your `.js` file as entry point inside the `dist` folder. If you change `outDir` setting or folder name in your `tsconfig.json` the runtime isn't able to find the code to run because file controls the output location.

```json
{
"scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionApp1.dll",
}
```

**function.json:**

[image]

Ensure that the compiled JavaScript files are located in the `dist` folder.
Then, Run the `func start` command from the root directory of your function app to start the local development environment.

The host.json file contains all the configurations related to bindings. It should be in the root folder of the function-app, so that the configurations will be applied equally to all the functions in the function app.